# {"message":"This session is not valid for use with the REST API","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]

Tags: apex, rest-api, apex-webservice, session-id

I've created Connected APP - Auth Provider and Named Credentials in order to make Rest API

Apex Classes :

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Opportunity/*')
global class RestApiIntegration {
    
    @httpGet
    global static list<Opportunity> getOpps(){
        return [SELECT  id , Name FROM Opportunity];
    }
}
```

---

```
public with sharing class RestApiIntegrationController {
   
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void getCount(){
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('callout:testAPIntegration/services/apexrest/Opportunity');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
        request.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
        request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

    }
}
```

named Credentials Authentication Protocol : Oauth2

When i try to execute `RestApiIntegrationController.getCount();` in the anonymous windows it throws an error - how to fix this?

Comment: The named cred `callout:testAPIntegration` what kind of Indetity type  and Auhtntication protocol is added is there?

Comment: You need to specify the identity type, authentication protocol, and credential details for your named credential to be able to make a callout to the external data source.

Comment: identity type is oauth2 , but its not a call to external data source i'm just trying to execute that soql in rest api ..

Comment: Your endpoint, in this post, is misspelled. Make sure you have the correct URL.

Answer (score 2):

I beleive this `RestApiIntegrationController` is getting called from UI, LWC or Aura.
So when you do a `UserInfo.getSessionID()`, it will fetch session Id of lightning domain. Which wont work for calling Rest APIs in salesforce.

If using named credential just make sure `Generate Authorization header` is checked.

[image]

And remove line `request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());`

This should set Authorization header properly from VFDomain automatically to the request and the response should be proper.

Also what @sfdcfox was pointing out was
`request.setEndpoint('callout:testAPIntegration/services/apexrest/Opporunity');`

Name `Opporunity` is incorrect as your urlMapping is `Opportunity`.

Comment: the issue was that i didn't specified the scope : *refresh_token api*